# Copy password hashed by bcrypt

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I'm storing my password using something like

```
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync('password', salt); //hash = $2a$10$MCNmLPkgiZ9jH9/0x4ZVJOvxYratODHJbcC6.X3vIDoxOfFwBYCpK
```

I wanted to move my database to another machine and BANG! all my passwords are wrong

if I do the same code in the new machine I get a different hash, this matters?

```
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync('password', salt); //hash = $2a$10$LLi4TyJ1oP69HQMkPpsExO4hinwW3SmURR0mqmB1ranCJX3ed5oDC
```

Comment: You are aware that the hash **should** be different every time, right? It doesn't matter if the hash is different, since you should be using the `compare` method to check them.

Comment: Salt is needed to mitigate hash tables attack. The `bcrypt.genSaltSync` generates salt using random function, thus it is different, as two computers rarely share random generators.  To solve the problem, you have to find out what is the salt on your old machine and set it equal on the new, then everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

That is by design. The workflow for checking a password does not involve generating a new salt, only using the existing salt when checking if the plaintext is correct.

From the [wikipedia on password salts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)):

> To understand the difference between cracking a single password and a
>   set of them, consider a single password file that contains hundreds of
>   usernames and passwords. Without a salt, an attacker could compute
>   hash(attempt[0]), and then check whether that hash appears anywhere in
>   the file. The likelihood of a match, i.e. cracking one of the
>   passwords with that attempt, increases with the number of passwords in
>   the file. If salts are present, then the attacker would have to
>   compute hash(salt[a] . attempt[0]), where "." denotes concatenation,
>   compare against entry A, then hash(salt[b] . attempt[0]), compare
>   against entry B, and so on. This defeats "reusing" hashes in attempts
>   to crack multiple passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the variable `salt`:

Imagine your database stores password of user X as `hash('mypass')`.

Intruder gets his hands on your database, and gets the hashed passwords. Now he is able to run a [Rainbow Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table), and if his pre-computed Rainbow table contains password 'mypass', he will easily find out what password user X used.

To mitigate, you can store passwords as `hash('mypass' + 'SERVER_CONSTANT')`
It purely defeats rainbow attack, even if intruder gets access to the `'SERVER_CONSTANT'`. It is a required standard now and is called [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

`bcrypt.genSalt(Sync)` method generates the Salt relying on unique properties of server's hardware. The`genSalt` is different for each computer (otherwise it defeats the purpose of Salt).

---

Solution:

`console.log(bcrypt.genSaltSync(10))` on your old machine. Let's say it is `ABCDE`.

Then do: `var salt = 'ABCDE'` on your new server. Using constant instead of genSalt is safe, but you will have to keep it private (out of public repositories, etc).